# Column values swapping while passing tvp to sql procedure from node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am facing a challenge that when I call a procedure and pass a table value parameter to it from  Node.JS . 2 particular Columns values are swapped when read by Stored Procedure. Below is my API end point code

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
const dataAccess = require("../DataAccess");

const fn_CreateProd = async function (product) {
  let errmsg = "";
  let objBlankTableStru = {};
  let connPool = null;
  await sql
    .connect(global.config)
    .then((pool) => {
      global.connPool = pool;
      
      productsStru = pool.request().query("select * from products where 1=2");

      return productsStru;
    })
    .then(productsStru=>{
      objBlankTableStru.products = productsStru

      productsOhStru = global.connPool.request().query("select * from products_oh where 1=2");
      
      return productsOhStru
    })
    .then((productsOhStru) => {
      objBlankTableStru.products_oh = productsOhStru
      
      let objTvpArr = [
        {
          uploadTableStru: objBlankTableStru,
        },
        {
          tableName : "products",
          tvpName: "tvp_products",
          tvpPara: "tblProds"
        },
        {
          tableName : "products_oh",
          tvpName: "tvp_product_oh",
          tvpPara: "tblProdsOh",
        }        
      ];

      newResult = dataAccess.getPostResult(
        objTvpArr,
        "sp3s_ins_products_tvp",
        product
      );

      console.log("Result of Execute Final procedure", newResult);
      return newResult;
    })
    .then((result) => {
      // console.log("Result of proc", result);
      if (!result.recordset[0].errmsg)
        errmsg = "Products Inserted successfully";
      else errmsg = result.recordset[0].errmsg;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Enter catch of Posting prod", err.message);
      errmsg = err.message;
      if (errmsg == "") {
        errmsg = "Unknown error from Server... ";
      }
    })
    .finally((resp) => {
      sql.close();
    });
  return { retStatus: errmsg };
};

module.exports = fn_CreateProd;
```

Below is the reference code of Function Getpostresult

```
const getPostResult = (tvpNamesArr, procName, sourceData,singleTableData) => {
  let arrtvpNamesPara = [];
  let prdTable = null;
  let newSrcData = [];

  let uploadTable = tvpNamesArr[0];

  for (i = 1; i <= tvpNamesArr.length - 1; i++) {
    let tvpName = tvpNamesArr[i].tvpName;
    let tvpNamePara = tvpNamesArr[i].tvpPara;
    let TableName = tvpNamesArr[i].tableName

    let srcTable = uploadTable.uploadTableStru[TableName]
    srcTable = srcTable.recordset.toTable(tvpName);

    let newsrcTable = Array.from(srcTable.columns);

    newsrcTable = newsrcTable.map((i) => {
      i.name = i.name.toUpperCase();
      return i;
    });
    if (!singleTableData)
        newSrcData = sourceData.filter(obj=>{
            return (obj.tablename.toUpperCase()===TableName.toUpperCase())
        })
    else 
    {
        newSrcData = sourceData
    }    

    console.log(`Filtered Source data for Table:${TableName}`,newSrcData)
    prdTable = generateTable(newsrcTable, newSrcData, tvpName);

    arrtvpNamesPara.push({ name: tvpNamePara, value: prdTable });
  }

  const newResult = execute(procName, arrtvpNamesPara);
  return newResult;
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.then()`-style `Promise` chaining when you can use `await` - your function is already `async` so you should fix that.

Comment: I am using .then()-style chaining to handle the errors and finally block to close the sql connection..How shall I be able to handle errors without this chaining..?? Do you think that this chaining is the root cause of my problem..?

Comment: No, I don't believe the chaining will cause any problems, but using `await` results in cleaner, easier-to-read code. You can handle errors by using `try { await somePromise(); } catch( err ) { ... } finally { .. }`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ..I will try to put this practice in future.. But Can you help me to resolve my current issue..??

Comment: I can't, sorry - I'm not familiar with using SQL Server through NodeJS. I can only offer general hints; for example, you say that "columns are being swapped" by the time they get to your procedure. Have you used XEvents to see the actual SQL being executed? Where and how are your table-type mappings configured?

Comment: Can you suggest me which Database is best suited to be used with Node.js APP..??